# How can one plot in 3D a matrix with LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matrices, 3d

I have a problem with drawing a 3d plot in TikZ. I have a matrix of size (n*m) n is the number of points in the x-direction and m is the number of points in the y-direction and the values in the matrix are the z coordinates. For example the array matrix in (1,2) in z value for point 1 in x direction and point 2 in y direction.
How can I plot this matrix in LaTeX?

**EDIT** Here is a sample of the matrix I would like to plot (z coordinate), with the row index as the x coordinate and the column index as the y coordinate:

```
(1.0514 ,1.1092 ,1.2479,1.383, 1.4261) 
(1.1294 ,1.247, 1.36, 1.392, 1.304) 
(1.1049,1.1466, 1.2459, 1.3397, 1.362) 
(1.1257,1.161, 1.2445, 1.3218, 1.3356)
```

Comment: can you include a small portion of your data to make sure you are looking for either a scatter plot or a surface parametrization?

Comment: you can edit your question instead

Comment: a part of my matrix is in the following and I want to plot a surface,                                           (1.0514 ,1.1092 ,1.2479,1.383, 1.4261 )          (1.1294 ,1.247, 1.36, 1.392, 1.304  )            (1.1049,1.1466, 1.2459, 1.3397, 1.362 )            (1.1257,1.161, 1.2445, 1.3218, 1.3356)

Answer (score 6):

Using the data you provided, here is a simple way to plot the surface:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis} 
\addplot3[surf] coordinates{
(0,0,1.0514) (0,1,1.1092) (0,2,1.2479) (0,3,1.3830) (0,4,1.4261)

(1,0,1.1294) (1,1,1.2470) (1,2,1.3600) (1,3,1.3920) (1,4,1.3040)

(2,0,1.1049) (2,1,1.1466) (2,2,1.2459) (2,3,1.3397) (2,4,1.3620)

(3,0,1.1257) (3,1,1.1610) (3,2,1.2445) (3,3,1.3218) (3,4,1.3356)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It yields this output

[image: Output]

**Remark 1** This is a very simple code and it is possible to much more complex things using the pgfplots (cf [this webpage](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html)).

**Remark 2** If your matrix is *big*, you may want to process it first to get the coordinates in a file rather than entering them manually. For this many options are available using different softwares.

**EDIT** Another method for the same output (and for big matrices), the idea is adapted from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111301/31058):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={-65}{45}]
\addplot3[raw gnuplot,surf]
            gnuplot[id={surf}]{%
set pm3d map interpolate 0,0;
splot 'data.txt' matrix using 1:2:($3);};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

%This part of the code is here only for comparison purpose
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[view={-65}{45}]
\addplot3[surf] coordinates{
(0,0,1.0514) (1,0,1.1092) (2,0,1.2479) (3,0,1.3830) (4,0,1.4261)

(0,1,1.1294) (1,1,1.2470) (2,1,1.3600) (3,1,1.3920) (4,1,1.3040)

(0,2,1.1049) (1,2,1.1466) (2,2,1.2459) (3,2,1.3397) (4,2,1.3620)

(0,3,1.1257) (1,3,1.1610) (2,3,1.2445) (3,3,1.3218) (4,3,1.3356)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**NOTE** The `data.txt` file is the following

```
1.0514 1.1092 1.2479 1.3830 1.4261
1.1294 1.2470 1.3600 1.3920 1.3040
1.1049 1.1466 1.2459 1.3397 1.3620
1.1257 1.1610 1.2445 1.3218 1.3356
```

And its output:

[image: Second Output]

Comment: Is there any way to plot 3D in Latex without reshaping my Matrix?

Comment: @Hana In which kind of file is your matrix stored? Which format exactly are you using within this file?

Comment: @Hana See my edit for plotting directly your matrix without reshaping it (or at least not with LaTeX ;)).

Comment: my data is in txt format, thank you for your Helpful answer Ludovic.

Comment: Typically, matrix data is serialized either in rowwise ordering or in column-wise ordering and is written to a file (i.e. one triple `X Y Z` per line). This is understood out-of-the-box by `pgfplots` and its `\addplot table` handle.