# PGFplots, memory and GNUplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

My question is quite simple. I generate a lot of plots for my thesis in PGFPlots, which I generate in separate PDF files using the standalone package (could not get shell escape to work properly). The data files are quite large, so I need to compile with LuaLaTeX (this is also the reason for generating separate PDF files). So my question is: Will using `\addplot gnuplot...` solve the problem with TEX main memory size? Or will I still need to generate separate PDF files?

Comment: Something that helps is to have one plot per page. (What is the problem with using LuaLaTeX?) See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13697/how-can-one-predict-pgfplots-memory-overload

Comment: You ask "Will using \addplot gnuplot... solve the problem with tex main memory size? Or will I still need to generate separate PDF files?"  What I'm curious about, is if there's any reason why you haven't tried it?  Also, you may want to have a look at the externalization library of TikZ.  This can allow you to have the code all in the main TeX file(s), and figures are automatically exported and compiled as separate PDfs and then automatically included (and they are recompiled if changed, also automatically).

Comment: Oh, well. This is a classic example of "when you ask for help, you automaticly solve your problem on your own". This time around, I managed to get externalize to work, and combined it with this solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29142/automagically-scale-tikz-picture-and-use-externalization in order to use automatic scaling of tikzfigure. The only issue now is that the PDF's are not updated automaticly when i change the tikz code.